# Return only top-level navigation items from a menu using wp_get_nav_menu_items

Tags: functions, theme-development, menus, navigation

I have the following function in my project:

```
function cr_get_menu_items($menu_location)
{
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = get_term($locations[$menu_location], 'nav_menu');
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
}
```

The function is used in my theme like this:

```
  <?php $nav = cr_get_menu_items('navigation_menu') ?>
  <?php foreach ($nav as $link): ?>
    <a href="<?= $link->url ?>"><?= $link->title ?></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This currently returns all navigation items present in my menu - parent/top-level and sub navigation. I am wondering how to alter this to **exclude** all sub navigation items. I only want to display the parent/top-level items.

Comment: i don't believe the selected answer adequately answers the OP's question as worded... "Return only top-level navigation items" seems very clear to me to indicate nav menu items with no `menu_item_parent`... the selected answer does provide a solution IF the question was "Return only top-level pages as navigation items"... @Aness answered below and seems to provide the solution best fitting the OP's question (even if it is disappointing to have to post-filter the menu items). MY QUESTION : can/should we reword the OP's question to better match the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at `wp_get_nav_menu_items` [code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/).

It takes two parameters:

- `$menu` - (int|string|WP_Term) (Required) Menu ID, slug, name, or object,
- `$args` - (array) (Optional) Arguments to pass to get_posts().

So we can use `get_posts` args in here... And if we want to get only top-level posts, then `post_parent` arg comes useful...

So something like this should do the trick:

```
function cr_get_menu_items($menu_location)
{
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = get_term($locations[$menu_location], 'nav_menu');
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id, array('post_parent' => 0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for `post_parent`, it looks like some undocumented secret feature… in the referencet docs link it's not a single word about it.

Comment: @ilic `post_parent` works because all the arguments from `get_posts()` are available -- which is thoroughly documented.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
function cr_get_menu_items($Your_menu_location)
{
  $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations();
  $YourmenuID = $menuLocations[$Your_menu_location];
  $YourNavItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($YourmenuID);
}
```

`$Your_menu_location` is a string variable representing the menu name like `'navigation_menu'` or `'primary'` depending on how you registered your menu in `functions.php` , The function is used in my theme like this:

```
<?php
  $menuitems = cr_get_menu_items('navigation_menu') ;
  foreach ( (array)$menuitems as $menuitem ) 
  {
    if (!$menuitem->menu_item_parent )
    echo '<a class="nav-link" href="'.$navItem->url.'">'.$navItem->title.' </a>';
  }
?>
```